# JQuery .replaceWith function only provides raw html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm having small problem on my `ajax` response that return `raw html` and no script is executed, hence `raw html` is provided without `jquery ui` scripts executed.

Here are the details:

---

I am currently on ASP.NET MVC, I would like to communicate with
   server to fet data somewhere, and return in terms of object.

Razor able to handle the model and display the data for me.

I need jquery for the `tab` functionality, helpful for organize data.

---

**The Problem**

Before I call ajax response, the `jquery` runs perfectly as shown image below:

[image]

I can access each tabs by clicking the header, and it provides different details. This is 100% copied from official jquery documentation for tabs as shown [here](https://jqueryui.com/tabs/)

When I click the submit button it will call `get request` to the server and handle the data. Now I can update the details based on newer data. But when I try to click submit it returns this:

[image]

As seen here, it broke the jquery script hence just showing what's inside the html code.

I can assure the problem is not on the jquery, as I have tested to display form when clicked as shown here. Note the code below doesn;t reflect image above as before click `normal response`, it would not show the details like first picture.

```
string disp = "none";
if (ViewBag.Message == "AJAX")
{
    disp = "block";
}

<div id="timetableList" style="display: @disp">
```

This means that the updated with new data. So the problem is not inside the jquery. What the `ajax` did is to replace the div from old data to new data as shown here:

```
var ajaxFormSubmit = function () {
    var $form = $(this);
    var options = {
        url: $form.attr("action"),
        type: $form.attr("method"),
        data: $form.serialize()
    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {
        var $target = $($form.attr("data-otf-target"));
        var $newHtml = $(data);
        $target.replaceWith($newHtml);
        $newHtml.effect("highlight");           
    });

    return false;
};
```

In here the `.done(function (data))`, data passed is the new html that has been updated, I checked it while debugging:

[image]

```
"\r\n<div id=\"timetableList\">\r\n <ul>\r\n <li><a href=\"#tabs-1\">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>\r\n <li><a href=\"#tabs-2\">Proin dolor</a></li>\r\n <li><a href=\"#tabs-3\">Aenean lacinia</a></li>\r\n </ul>\r\n ......
```

We can say that ajax will replace the data with new html but doesn't execute the jquqry as shown above. Is there a way so that it `load scripts` so that can show the result as expected.

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you replace the HTML, any javascript code in that HTML won’t be executed. So you should execute those javascript code after replacing the HTML.

Comment: So what should I put after ` $newHtml.effect("highlight");` cause when I put inside html, it will treated as raw html again? am i correct?

Comment: Yes. That’s raw html and you execute the code after replacing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey you can simply call the tabs method in ajax response function just after replaceWith method.
something

$("your tabs element id").tabs()